# React + Mapbox: Sample implementation of `getRenderedFeatures` in Deck.gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I have a project using a React, Mapbox, and Deck.gl stack. I'm trying to query the features on a styled map but am having trouble implementing Deck.gl's `getRenderedFeatures` function, even after looking at the [documentation](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/mvt-layer).

My current React component:

```
<DeckGL
          {...deckGLProps}
          layers={layers}
          onViewportChange={() => console.log(mapRef)}
          ref={mapRef}
          getRenderedFeatures={(e) => console.log(e)}
        >
          <StaticMap
            ref={mapRef}
            visible={!level}
            {...staticMapProps}
            {...viewport}
            mapStyle={mapStyle[0]}
          />
        </DeckGL>
```

I understand that querying `getRenderedFeatures` on `onViewportLoad` is recommended, but I can't find an implementation that works.

Does anyone have a working implementation of `getRenderedFeatures` or a link to better documentation on the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `MVTLayer` right?

[`getRenderedFeatures` is a method](https://codepen.io/AdriSolid/pen/QWdYYoe) of `MVTLayer` class, you need to access it from here, not from the deck instance.

The logic could be:

1. Render the `MVTLayer`
2. Listen `onViewStateChange` from the deck instance with some debounce
3. Then call `getRenderedFeatures`

Something like:

```
function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}

const YourMVTLayer = new MVTLayer({ ... });

function getViewportFeatures() {
  const viewportFeatures = YourMVTLayer.getRenderedFeatures();
  console.log(viewportFeatures);
}

// render
<DeckGL
 ...
 layers={[YourMVTLayer]}
 onViewportChange={debounce(getViewportFeatures, 500)}
/>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/AdriSolid/pen/QWdYYoe) another example using the scripting API

Comment: Thanks again! This answered the question I posed, so I accepted the answer. I was wondering, though: is it possible to get features from a Mapbox style? Say I have a heatmap of polygons and want to query the values