# React, Mapbox, & Deck.gl: How get features under the mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I'm trying to replicate [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/) example from the Mapbox documentation in React and Deck.gl. I've discovered the `getRenderedFeatures` function in Deck.gl, helped by the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536418/react-mapbox-sample-implementation-of-getrenderedfeatures-in-deck-gl) question.

My confusion stems from creating an `MVTLayer` with the style I want to query. My current code:

```
export default function Map() {
  const PopulationLayer = new MVTLayer({
    data: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
    getFillColor: [192, 192, 192],
    pointRadiusMinPixels: 3,
    uniqueIdProperty: "cartodb_id",
    pickable: true,
  });

  function debounce(fn, ms) {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        timer = null;
        fn.apply(this, args);
      }, ms);
    };
  }

  function getViewportFeatures() {
    const viewportFeatures = PopulationLayer.getRenderedFeatures();
    console.log(viewportFeatures);
  }

  const view = {
    latitude: 41.4,
    longitude: 2.18,
    zoom: 5,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DeckGL
        container={"map"}
        mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"}
        initialViewState={view}
        controller={true}
        layers={[PopulationLayer]}
        onViewStateChange={debounce(getViewportFeatures, 500)}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      >
        <StaticMap mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN} />
      </DeckGL>
    </>
  );
}
```

This line - `data: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"` - is giving me an error: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): An error occurred fetching TileJSON: TypeError: Failed to fetch`. I assume this implies that `MVTLayer` was unable to parse the Mapbox style.

**Is it possible to use `MVTLayer` with Mapbox styles? Is there an alternative way of achieving this?** I ultimately want to use a custom style that contains a heatmap that shows the heatmaps values on hover. Something along [these](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-2/) lines. I figured that getting this to work on a standard style was a good first step.